# Почему на удалённом хостинге не работает file_get_contents(), а на локальном сервере работает?

Tags: php, хостинг

Почему этот код:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.site.com");
echo $html;
?>
```

на локальном сервере OpenServer выводит HTML-код  сайта [www.site.com](http://www.site.com), а на удалённом условно платном хостинге выводит пустую строку? Из-за чего это может быть? Может из-за каких-то настроек, которые я могу или не могу изменить, или нужно искать другой хостинг? За раннее спасибо.

Comment: Читайте логи ошибок php (они ж у хостинга где-то должны быть наверное?)

Comment: allow_url_fopen   отключен может

Comment: **phpinfo()** показывает, что **allow_url_fopen** = **on**. Это значит включён? Ещё в файле **error.log** появляется такая ошибка: `[Fri Jul 01 17:42:35.357726 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 83684] [client 195.10.210.70:56367] AH01215: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://site.ru): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /virt/homes/opan/htdocs/test.php on line 2: /virt/homes/opan/cgi-bin/php Предупреждение, не удалось открыть поток. Отказано в доступе` Что это может означать?

Comment: Оказывается, прописал в file_get_contents(адрес другого сайта) и заработало. Выходит, от сайта зависит.

Comment: Одним словом, я так понял, что сейчас это работает, если сайт с адресом в скобках находится на том же  хостинге, что и скрипт. В противном случае - пустая строка. Буду ещё искать другой хостинг.